# How to position a path point in sketch

Tags: path, sketch-app

I was wondering if there was a way to change the position of a point in a path, using only one handler instead of moving both

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. To move an anchor point, you only need to grab the anchor point...? Moving the points in the handles won't move the anchor point, no matter how many handles you move.

Comment: You see, There are two handlers for each anchor point. I want to move each handler separately

Comment: You should find your answer here: [Vector Tool Documentation](https://sketchapp.com/docs/vector-editing/vector-tool)

Comment: @Joonas Thank you so much for sending me that link. I found my answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to 
Sketch documentation:

[Vector Tool](https://sketchapp.com/docs/vector-editing/vector-tool)

You can move each handler of an anchor point by holding down "**command**" key on your keyboard.